# Maxima: How to factor out a finite sum?

Tags: math, symbolic-math, maxima

This question is about humane representation of Maxima output.

**In short**, how do I make

```
b*d4 + b*d3 + b*d2 + b*d1 + a*sin(c4 + alpha) + a*sin(c3 + alpha) + a*sin(c2 + alpha) + a*sin(c1 + alpha)
```

look like

```
b*sum_{i=1}^{4} d_i + a*sum_{j=1}^{4}sin(c_i + \alpha)
```

where sum_{*}^{*}* is a summation sign and an expression with subscripts ?

**Or deeper**, how to properly model a finite set of items here ?

Consider a finite set of entities $x_i$ (trying to speak tex here) that are numbered from 1 to n where n is known. Let a function $F$ depend on several characteristics of those entities $c_ji = c_j(x_i), j = 1..k$ (k - also known) so that $F = F(c_11,...,c_kn)$.

Now when I try to implement that in Maxima and do things with it, it would yield sums and products of all kinds, where the numbered items are represented something like $c_1*a + c_2*a + c_3*a + c_4*a + d_1*b + d_2*b + d_3*b + d_4*b$ which you would write down on paper as $a*\sum_{i=1}^{4}c_i + b*sum_{i=1}^{4}d_i$.

So how can I make Maxima do that sort of expression contraction ?

To be more specific, here is an actual code example:
(Maxima output marked as ">>>")

```
/* let's have 4 entities: */
n: 4 $

/* F is a sum of similar components corresponding to each entity F = F_1 + F_2 + F_3 + F_4 */
F_i: a*sin(alpha + c_i) + b*d_i;
>>> b*d_i + a*sin(c_i + alpha)

/* defining the characteristics */
c(i) := concat(c, i) $
d(i) := concat(d, i) $

/* now let's see what F looks like */

/* first, we should model the fact that we have 4 entities somehow: */
F_i(i) := subst(c(i), c_i, subst(d(i), d_i, F_i)) $

/* now we can evaluate F: */
F: sum(F_i(i), i, 1, 4);
>>> b*d4 + b*d3 + b*d2 + b*d1 + a*sin(c4 + alpha) + a*sin(c3 + alpha) + a*sin(c2 + alpha) + a*sin(c1 + alpha)

/* at this point it would be nice to do something like:                */
/*     pretty(F);                                                      */
/* and get an output of:                                               */
/*     $b*\sum_{i=1}^{4}d_i + a*\sum_{j=1}^4 sin(c_j + \alpha)$        */
/* not to mention having Maxima write things in the same order as I do */
```

So, to sum up, there are three quetions here:

1. How do I factor out a sum from an expression like the one on top of this post ?
2. How do I properly let Maxima know what I'm speaking about here ?
3. How to make Maxima preserve my order of things in output ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to go about what I think you want.

```
(%i1) n: 4 $
(%i2) F(i) := a*sin(alpha + c[i]) + b*d[i];
(%o2)                  F(i) := a sin(alpha + c ) + b d
                                              i       i
(%i3) 'sum(F(i), i,1,4);
                        4
                       ====
                       \
(%o3)                   >    (a sin(c  + alpha) + b d )
                       /             i               i
                       ====
                       i = 1
(%i4) declare (nounify(sum), linear);
(%o4)                                done
(%i5) 'sum(F(i), i,1,4);
                        4                         4
                       ====                      ====
                       \                         \
(%o5)                a  >    sin(c  + alpha) + b  >    d
                       /          i              /      i
                       ====                      ====
                       i = 1                     i = 1
(%i6)
```

The most important thing here is that I've written what we would call "c sub i" and "d sub i" as `c[i]` and `d[i]` respectively. These are indexed variables named `c` and `d`, and `i` is the index. It's not necessary for there to actually exist arrays or lists named `c` or `d`, and `i` might or might not have a specific value.

I have written `F` as an ordinary function. I've avoided the construction of variable names via `concat` and avoided the substitution of those names into an expression. I would like to emphasize that such operations are almost certainly not the best way to go about it.

In `%i3` note that I wrote the summation as `'sum(...)` which makes it a so-called noun expression, which means it is maintained in a symbolic form and not evaluated.

By default, summations are not treated as linear, so in `%i4` I declared summations as linear so that the result in `%o5` is as expected.

Maxima doesn't have a way to collect expressions such as `a1 + a2 + a3` back into a symbolic summation, but perhaps you don't need such an operation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By the way, how do I compute the sum over actual lists of values `c_i` and `d_i` ?

Comment: And, what's more tricky, when actual values are known for only a subset of all indexed variables ? Like if we have a sum of `(a_i + b_i)^2` for `i` in `1..4`, but we only know that `a[i]` are in `[4, 5, 6, 7]`, while `b[i]` are unknown, then the expected result would be `126 + sum(b_i^2) + 8*b_1 + ...`. Not sure if this is even possible nor required (maybe in such cases we humans just should step in and do the thing), but curious whether Maxima offers a way to do so.

Comment: Well, `a:[4, 5, 6, 7]; sum((a[i] + b[i])^2, i, 1, 4);` yields `(b[4]+7)^2 +(b[3]+6)^2 +(b[2]+5)^2 +(b[1]+4)^2`. From that, `expand(%);` yields `b[4]^2 +14*b[4] +b[3]^2 +12*b[3] +b[2]^2 +10*b[2] +b[1]^2 +8*b[1] +126`. So there's no problem with a's having values and b's not having values, although the form of the result is somewhat messy. In general, Maxima is happy with expressions in which some variables have values and some do not.